# Given a tuple with arbitrary number of vectors holding different types how do I extract the vector with minimum size?

Tags: c++, c++11, template-meta-programming, generic-programming

In my application I generate a tuple with many vectors holding values. I would like to have a generic way of iterating over the tuple to extract the single vector with least values.

For example:

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(std::vector<int>({1,2}), std::vector<double>({1.0, 2.0, 3.0}));
```

How do I extract the vector which holds the least values?

Comment: extract first, extract second, compare sizes?

Comment: I clarified the question - by the time I get the tuple I can't hard code specific entries because I don't know how many vectors the tuple holds.

Comment: Does each vector hold a distinct element type, or can you have multiple e.g. `vector<int>`s?

Comment: Are you willing to use a `std::variant<std::vector<int>, std::vector<double>>` for your example?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, but I guess I'll have to settle for `boost::variant`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume we either have no duplicates in our pack of types, or [a way of removing them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13840677/2610810), and also a [C++11 backport](https://gist.github.com/jappa/62f30b6da5adea60bad3) of [`std::index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

```
#include <map>
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/variant>
#include <future/index_sequence>

namespace detail {
    template<typename Variant, typename Tuple, std::size_t... Is>
    std::map<std::size_t, std::function<Variant(const Tuple &)>> from_tuple_map(index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        return { { Is, [](const Tuple & tup){ return std::get<Is>(tup); } }... };
    }

    struct GetSize
    {
        template<typename T>
        std::size_t operator()(const std::vector<T> & vec){ return vec.size(); }
    }; // becomes C++14 generic lambda
}

template<typename... Ts>
boost::variant<Ts...> from_tuple(const std::tuple<Ts...> & tup)
{
    auto map = detail::from_tuple_map<boost::variant<Ts...>, std::tuple<Ts...>>(make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Ts)>());
    auto get_size = GetSize{};
    std::size_t best = 0;
    std::size_t len = visit(get_size, map[best](tup));
    for (std::size_t trial = 1; trial < sizeof...(Ts); ++trial)
    {
        std::size_t trial_len = visit(get_size, map[trial](tup));
        if (trial_len > len)
        {
            best = trial;
            len = trial_len;
        }
    }
    return map[best](tup);
}

int main()
{
    auto x = from_tuple(std::make_tuple(std::vector<int>({1,2}), std::vector<double>({1.0, 2.0, 3.0})));
    visit([](const auto & a){ std::cout << a[1]; }, x);
}
```

[See it live (using C++17 compiler)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/85f0909ced53ccd4)

Comment: @caleth thank you for the answer. The map trick is great, unfortunately it won't work in g++ 6.5 (compiler bug). I'll try upgrading to 7.4 to see if it got fixed.

Answer (score 3):

> Given a tuple with vectors holding **different types** how do I extract the vector with minimum size?

<s>You can't</s> You can't directly.

Because they are different types, the decision is based on values (not on types), so you can't decide the type extracted compile time (`std::tuple` can't be `constexpr`), and C++ is a strong typed language.

The <s>best</s> simplest thing you can do is extract the **index** of the vector with minimum size. Because in this case the value extracted is an integer (`std::size_t`, by example) and you can iterate the over the vectors in the tuple to select the one with less elements.

Different is if you have to extract the `std::array` with minimum size

```
auto t = std::make_tuple(std::array<int, 2u>({1,2}),
                         std::array<double, 3u>({1.0, 2.0, 3.0}));
```

because the size (`2u` for the first, `3u` for the second) is know compile time so you can select the second array compile time.

If you can use C++17, you can use `std::variant`, so a type that can contain all types of your tuple.

As pointed by Caleth (thanks) if you can use only C++11/C++14 with boost libraries, you can use `boost::variant`. But I don't know it so I can't show you a specific example (but you can see the Caleth's answer)

The following is an example with a two-types tuple

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
std::variant<T1, T2> getLess (std::tuple<T1, T2> const & tp)
 {
   std::variant<T1, T2>  v;

   if ( std::get<0>(tp).size() < std::get<1>(tp).size() )
       v = std::get<0>(tp);
   else
       v = std::get<1>(tp);

   return v;
 }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int>     vi {1, 2, 3};
   std::vector<double>  vd {1.0, 2.0};

   auto gl = getLess(std::make_tuple(vi, vd));
 }
```

This works with a two types tuple. But with a N-types tuple (with `N` high) become complicated because you can't write something as

```
auto min_length = std::get<0>(tp).size();
auto min_index  = 0u;

for ( auto ui = 1u ; ui < N ; ++ui )
   if ( std::get<ui>(tp).size() < min_length )
    {
       min_length = std::get<ui>(tp).size();
       min_index  = ui;
    }
```

because you can't pass to `std::get<>()` a run-time value as `ui`.

Same problem assigning the variant. You can't simply write

```
v = std::get<min_index>(tp);
```

because `min_index` is a run-time value.

You have to pass through a `switch()`

```
switch ( min_length )
 {
   case 0: v = std::get<0>(tp); break;
   case 1: v = std::get<1>(tp); break;
   case 2: v = std::get<2>(tp); break;
   case 3: v = std::get<3>(tp); break;
   case 4: v = std::get<4>(tp); break;

   // ...

   case N-1: v = std::get<N-1>(tp); break;
 };
```

or something similar.

As you can see it's complicated and more complicated become if you want that the `getLess()` function is a variadic one.

For the variadic case, the best I can imagine (but is a C++17 solution; see Caleth's answer for a C++11 solution) is to use an helper function and template folding as follows.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template <typename ... Ts, std::size_t ... Is>
auto getLessHelper (std::tuple<Ts...> const & tp,
                    std::index_sequence<0, Is...> const &)
 {
   std::variant<Ts...> var_ret  { std::get<0>(tp) };
   std::size_t         min_size { std::get<0>(tp).size() };

   ((std::get<Is>(tp).size() < min_size ? (var_ret = std::get<Is>(tp),
                                           min_size = std::get<Is>(tp).size())
                                        : 0u), ...);

   return var_ret;
 }

template <typename ... Ts>
auto getLess (std::tuple<Ts...> const & tp)
 { return getLessHelper(tp, std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{}); }

int main ()
 {
   std::vector<int>     vi {1, 2, 3};
   std::vector<double>  vd {1.0, 2.0};
   std::vector<float>   vf {1.0f};

   auto gl = getLess(std::make_tuple(vi, vd, vf));

   std::cout << std::visit([](auto const & v){ return v.size(); }, gl)
       << std::endl; // print 1, the size() of vf
 }
```

Comment: Once you have the index you can then get the vector, of course, but indeed it's going to require some type erasure - probably via a visitor and a variant. Probably cause to revisit the design requirements.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit could you clarify how that may be done? I did get as far as getting the index.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes: `std::variant` is a way, in a sense, to return al types together. But require C++17 and this question is tagged C++11.

Comment: I just upgraded to g++ 6.5, so have partial c++17 support, but not std::variant unfortunately.

Comment: I have access to boost, so if I have to use it to higher degree than I have before I am a OK with it.

Comment: @max66 OP is already using Boost, which provides `boost::variant` (just as it provided `shared_ptr` before C++ did). Worst case you can make a tagged union yerself

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - OK: I'm correcting my answer using `std::variant` and C++17 (sorry but I not use boost).

Comment: @max66 To be clear, I didn't think any correction was necessary - I was just complimenting your answer by adding an observation about the OP's situation

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - well... a little correction is appropriate

Comment: @Caleth - Ok; thanks. I don't know `boost::variant` so I've added a C++17 example mentioning that exist `boost::variant`.

Comment: @max66 thank you very much for your answer. It was quite revealing, and taught me a new expansion trick.

Comment: @NindzAI - It's a pity you can't completely use C++17: as you can see, template folding is very useful. But the `map` is Caleth's answer is a valid alternative.