# Pointer to member function, always prints as "1"

Tags: c++

I was trying a new approach to the answer I gave to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56292104/hashing-types-at-compile-time-in-c17-c2a), I thought that returning the address of a member function as ID could be a path worth to explore:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    void f(){};

    using mp = void(S::*)();

    template <typename T>
    static constexpr mp ID()
    {
        return &S::f<T>;
    }
};
```

I thought that every instantiation of `S::f` would have an unique address which will be shared in every translation unit and even might be available at compile time, so I tested it:

```
std::cout << S::ID<char>() << '\n';
```

And the output was `1`; quite unexpected to be honest (I was expecting the value to be printed as an hex number, like other pointers), but moving forward I tried other types:

```
std::cout << S::ID<char>() << '\n';  // Prints '1'.
std::cout << S::ID<char>() << '\n';  // Expecting '1', got '1'.
std::cout << S::ID<short>() << '\n'; // Execting something different to '1', got '1'.
```

At this point, I realized that the `1` value wasn't the "*adress of the member function inside the object*" because two different functions (`void S::f<char>()` and `void S::f<short>()`) shared the same *address*. So I've tried another approach:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    static auto ID()
    {
        return +[]{};
    }
};
```

Captureless lambdas can be converted to function pointers and each lambda has an unique type even if its contents are the same, so I was expecting some random-*ish* values but got `1` again:

```
std::cout << S::ID<char>() << '\n';  // Expecting '0x????????' Prints '1'.
std::cout << S::ID<char>() << '\n';  // Expecting '0x????????' Prints '1'.
std::cout << S::ID<short>() << '\n'; // Expecting '0x!!!!!!!!' Prints '1'.
```

---

At this point, I just want to know what those `1` means and why are all of them `1` even if the *expected* behaviour is that all of them must yield a different value.

Comment: `1` is a `bool`...

Comment: So, it is entering through the `ostream operator<<(ostream &, bool)`?!

Comment: The reference will tell you that pointers to functions and to members are cast to `bool` rather than `void*`, and that is what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, and this is because there are no implicit conversions to `void*` from a pointer to (member) function like there are from a pointer to object.

Comment: Pointer to member is not a simple "pointer" type. It may be an index into the vtable, or it may be a pointer to the actual function instance. It may have to handle virtual inheritance, and a few other nasties, so it has a number of fields.

Comment: To confirm, you could try doing `std::cout << std::boolalpha` before other prints, and you should see "true" (or possibly a translation) instead of "1".