# Making Types in a Parameter Pack unique

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I am trying to implement a class that takes a number of events and then returns the first event that becomes active.

The class is something like

```
template <typename ...Event>
class OneOf {
public:
    OneOf(Event... events);
    std::variant<Event...> getReturn();
private:
    std::tuple<Event...> m_events;
};
```

The problem is that the template may take duplicates of the same type for the event but the `std::variant` will only accept unique event types.

How do I define the `std::variant` in such a way so that all duplicate types from my parameter pack are eliminated?

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13827319/eliminate-duplicate-entries-from-c11-variadic-template-arguments) is a C++11 solution.  I would think it could be shortened using C++17 and fold expressions.